# React Native: Updating state in onLayout gives "Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition"

Tags: react-native

I have a component in React Native which updates it's state once it knows what size it is.
Example:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
        ...

        return (
            <View onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}>
                <Image source={this.state.imageSource} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    onLayout(event) {
        ...

        this.setState({
            imageSource: newImageSource
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

This gives the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I guess the onLayout function is called while still rendering (which can be good, the sooner the update, the better). What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't use the component's size from within the render function unless you're *very* careful, because any change in child components or styles could cause the size to change, which may result in an infinite loop.  If you *aren't* using the size in the render function, it shouldn't be stored in `state`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got around this by using the measure function, you will have to wait until the scene is fully complete before measuring to prevent incorrect values (i.e. in componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate). Here's an example:

```js
  measureComponent = () => {
    if (this.refs.exampleRef) {
      this.refs.exampleRef.measure(this._logLargestSize);
    }
  }

  _logLargestSize = (ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
    if (height > this.state.measureState) {
      this.setState({measureState:height});
    }
  }

render() {
  return (
    <View ref = 'exampleRef' style = {{minHeight:  this.props.minFeedbackSize}}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is a solution from documentation for such cases

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
...

  render() {
    ...

    return (
        <View>
            <Image ref="image" source={this.state.imageSource} />
        </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Now you can get your component from this.refs.image
  }

  ...
}
```

But for my opinion it's better to do such things [onload](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onload)